# Remove required attribute from a property at runtime

Tags: c#

I want to be able remove the required attribute from a property of a type in conditional circumstances. Let's say I have a class like this;

```
public partial class UserTest
{
    [Key]
    public int USERID { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string USERNAME { get; set; }

    [StringLength(250)]
    public string USERSURNAME { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string TEST { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is that, I want to be able to remove the `[Required]` attribute from the property named `TEST` at runtime so that when I initialize a `UserTest` object, the compiler won't be forcing me to give a value to the `TEST` property. It does not must be literally "removing" the attribute but another methods are welcomed as well such as giving it a default value at runtime. How would I achieve such a task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't remove an attribute at runtime, sorry. You could although inherit from `Attribute` and create your own.

Comment: You cant remove an attribute at runtime; they are evaluated at compile time. You will need to either create your own custom attribute or use another form of validation.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are set at compile time. It's bound to a type at class level, not to an instance.

You should implement your own `ValidationAttribute` (i.e. subclass it). Within its  `IsValid` Method, you can return true or false to your needs.